# meaning and usage of "in order the more"

Tags: meaning, phrases, adverbs, definite-articles, comparatives

I have just come across a phrase I have never seen before:

> I do not so in order to undermine the status of xy but, on the contrary, *in order the more* securely to identify certain aspects.

A quick internet research has shown me that the phrase apparently really exists and me and from the respectice contexts I guess it must be equivalent to *in order to [identify] more [securely]*.

Is this right? Is this phrase commonly used or rather strange?

Comment: The sentence is fine as it is. Takes some careful re-reading.

Comment: @Kris- It's not parsing for me.  I think the *to* needs to stay with *order*:  "in order to the more securely identify."  And even then it's a bit unwieldy.  I think I'd drop the *the* and make it: *on the contrary, in order to more securely identify...*

Comment: I think the _ in order the more securely_ phrase is stilted and pretentious in the 21st century. I agree with Jim's preference: _in order to more securely identify_. It's clear and easy to understand and not in a lower register.

Comment: The writer is avoiding splitting "to identify" and putting the adverb before it in high-register fashion, "more securely to identify". He's then adding "in order to" and getting confused. The word *the* is superfluous. I would use "in order to identify certain aspects more securely".

Comment: @AndrewLeach  I think you meant to write "**the** more securely to identify"?

Answer (score 4):

The entire sentence needs rewriting. I suggest:

> I do not do so to undermine the status of xy but, on the contrary, to
>   identify more securely certain aspects.

In other words, *in order* adds an unnecessary complication, and a second *do* is required at the start of the sentence.

*In order the more securely to . . .* is not ungrammatical, but it rather looks as if the writer is desperately trying to avoid placing anything between the particle *to* and the infinitive *identify*. If you must have *in order*, then Jim’s suggestions offer a solution.

Comment: Yes. In order to avoid splitting the infinitive, the author is splitting the conjunctive phrase "in order to", which is even less acceptable. The natural word-order is Andrew Leach's (not yet up when you posted), moving "more securely" to the end.